# How to Get Column index for Google data chart selection handler

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I took the following example for using google data chart with Selection handler. But it says it could not return Column index. 
It says it should 
anyone could give me some hints on how to implement the handler to select the column index?

```
// Note: This sample shows the select event.
// The select event is a generic select event,
// for selecting rows, columns, and cells.
// However, in this example, only rows are selected.
// Read more here: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/table.html#Events

function drawVisualization() {
  visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
  visualization.draw(data, null);

  // Add our selection handler.
  google.visualization.events.addListener(visualization, 'select', selectHandler);
}

// The selection handler.
// Loop through all items in the selection and concatenate
// a single message from all of them.
function selectHandler() {
  var selection = visualization.getSelection();
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
    var item = selection[i];
    if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(item.row, item.column);
      message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '} = ' + str + '\n';
    } else if (item.row != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(item.row, 0);
      message += '{row:' + item.row + ', (no column, showing first)} = ' + str + '\n';
    } else if (item.column != null) {
      var str = data.getFormattedValue(0, item.column);
      message += '{(no row, showing first), column:' + item.column + '} = ' + str + '\n';
    }
  }
  if (message == '') {
    message = 'nothing';
  }
  alert('You selected ' + message);
}
```